# Using MotionLayout OnSwipe on Item of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I try to achieve an animation on an item of my recycler view, a custom swipe, and for that, I tried to use the MotionLayout. 
Actually, it works fine if the trigger of the animation is a click, but when I want to put a swipe, it interferes with the swipe of the recycler view. Here's my scene :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@layout/chat_item_start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@layout/chat_item_end"
    motion:duration="500">

    <OnClick
        motion:targetId="@+id/background"
        motion:clickAction="toggle" />

    <!-- <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/background"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="right"
        motion:dragDirection="dragLeft" /> -->

    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

How look my list at the beginning :

[image]

And at the end, when I click on an item :

[image]

When I switch to OnSwipe trigger, the animation works but only if I strictly swipe horizontally, if, by mistake, my finger go a little up or down, the animation is stopped and don't even finish itself :

[image]

I think the problem comes because the recycler view also handles the swipe gesture, because when the animation stops (if I go a little up/down) the recycler moves as usually.

If I play too much with the swipe, I get this error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.VelocityTracker.addMovement(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
>           at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout$MyTracker.addMovement(MotionLayout.java:985)
>           at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionScene.processTouchEvent(MotionScene.java:1043)
>           at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.onTouchEvent(MotionLayout.java:2992)
>           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12515)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3024)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2705)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:444)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3397)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:402)
>           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12754)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5052)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4855)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4372)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4425)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4391)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4531)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4399)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4588)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4372)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4425)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4391)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4399)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4372)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7034)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7007)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6968)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7137)
>           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)

I have no idea how to properly dispatch the touch event between the MotionLayout and the RecyclerView, and if it's even possible at this stage, with the motion layout.

If anyone has an idea, thanks in advance!

UPDATE :

Here's the code to handle the touch event (disable/enable on the recyclerView)

The onTouchListener on the recyclerView Item

```
holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->

        val progress = holder.motion.progress

        when(motionEvent.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                x = motionEvent.x
                y = motionEvent.y
                Log.d("Event Down", "X : $x, Y : $y")
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP->{
                finalx = motionEvent.x
                finaly = motionEvent.y
                Log.d("Event Up", "X : $finalx, Y : $finaly")

                if(progress > 0.5 && progress != 1.0F ){
                    holder.motion?.transitionToEnd()
                }else{
                    holder.motion?.transitionToStart()
                }
                holder.itemView.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ->{
                val currentX = motionEvent.x
                val currentY = motionEvent.y

                val deltaX = abs(x - currentX)
                val deltaY = abs(y - currentY)


                if (deltaX > 1 && deltaY > 1 && deltaX > deltaY ){
                    holder.itemView.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                }
                Log.d("Event Move", "X : $currentX, Y : $currentY")
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

The transition listener

```
holder.motion.setTransitionListener(object: MotionLayout.TransitionListener{

        override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {}
        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
            Log.d("Animation started", "Start id : $p1")
            holder.itemView.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
            Log.d("Animation change ", "progress : $p3")
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
            val progress = holder.motion.progress
            opened = progress == 1.0f
            Log.d("Animation Completed", "progress : $progress")
            holder.itemView.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        }
    })
```

I use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` a bit everywhere because I've noticed different behavior and this code is the one that works the best, but still have the crash after playing around with the cells/scroll/animation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is the scroll of the recyclerview that is interrupting your animation. My suggestion would be to lock the recyclerviews scroll while an item is being swiped.

As for the crash, I am also trying to figure out a work around for that myself. The crash seems to be caused by addMovement(android.view.MotionEvent) being called without checking if the reference to VelocityTracker object is null. This is an issue motion layout itself.

**EDIT**: added code

```
class CustomLayoutManager(val context: Context?) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
private var isScrollEnabled = true
fun setScrollEnabled(flag: Boolean) {
    isScrollEnabled = flag
}

override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically()
}
```

above is the layout manager. its pretty simple just overriding the vertical scroll to set it with my flag which will be set later.

```
MotionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionTrigger(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, idStart: Int, idEnd: Boolean, progress: Float) {
        }

        override fun onTransitionStarted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, idStart: Int, idEnd: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, idStart: Int, idEnd: Int, progress: Float) {
            //Timber.d("ML: CHANGED ${p0?.currentState} endId:$p2 startid:$p1")
            if (motionLayout?.currentState != idStart && motionLayout?.currentState != idEnd) motionListener?.onTriggered()

        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, idCurrent: Int) {
            motionListener?.onComplete()

        }
    })
```

above is the transition listener. its inside a custom view in mine so you wont need the call backs if yours is just inside the recyclerview. all I am doing is checking in OnChanged that it is not at the start or end id. that is how you know the item is in motion. then in my adapter i have this

```
interface ScrollLockListener {
    fun onLockUnlock(shouldLock: Boolean)
}
fun setScrollLockListener(listener: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    scrollLockListener = object : ScrollLockListener {
        override fun onLockUnlock(shouldLock: Boolean) = listener(shouldLock)
    }
}

holder.item.setMotionListener(
                    { scrollLockListener?.onLockUnlock(false) },
                    { scrollLockListener?.onLockUnlock(true) })
```

this creates a callback for your adapter that allows you to set the the scroll lock from the activity or fragment. Then in your activity/fragment you just do

```
cardLayoutRecycler.layoutManager = CustomLayoutManager(context).also {
            recyclerAdapter.setScrollLockListener { isLocked -> it.setScrollEnabled(isLocked) }
        }
```

**EDIT**: for fixing the crash I ended up doing this

```
public class CustomMotionLayout extends MotionLayout {

public CustomMotionLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomMotionLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomMotionLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected MotionTracker obtainVelocityTracker() {
    return CustomMotionLayout.MyTracker.obtain();
}

/**
 * The only functional changes to this class are added null-checks and recursion avoidance in
 * @see MyTracker#getYVelocity(int)
 *
 * A possible desync issue in the official MotionLayout class can trigger a NullPointerException
 * here when the VelocityTracker object is accessed immediately after being recycled.
 */
private static class MyTracker implements MotionLayout.MotionTracker {
    VelocityTracker tracker;
    private static CustomMotionLayout.MyTracker me = new CustomMotionLayout.MyTracker();

    private MyTracker() {
    }

    public static CustomMotionLayout.MyTracker obtain() {
        me.tracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
        return me;
    }

    public void recycle() {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            this.tracker.recycle();
            this.tracker = null;
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            this.tracker.clear();
        }
    }

    public void addMovement(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            this.tracker.addMovement(event);
        }
    }

    public void computeCurrentVelocity(int units) {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            this.tracker.computeCurrentVelocity(units);
        }
    }

    public void computeCurrentVelocity(int units, float maxVelocity) {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            this.tracker.computeCurrentVelocity(units, maxVelocity);
        }
    }

    public float getXVelocity() {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            return this.tracker.getXVelocity();
        } else {
            return 0f;
        }
    }

    public float getYVelocity() {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            return this.tracker.getYVelocity();
        } else {
            return 0f;
        }
    }

    public float getXVelocity(int id) {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            return this.tracker.getXVelocity(id);
        } else {
            return 0f;
        }
    }

    public float getYVelocity(int id) {
        if (this.tracker != null) {
            return this.tracker.getYVelocity(id);
        } else {
            return 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It was my thought too, and that's what I did (I put an update with the relevant code), but the problem is still here...

I think maybe the MotionLayout isn't ready yet to be placed inside a recyclerView and handle the lifecycle of the items

Comment: I went with a different approach. I created a custom layout manager that allows me to lock the scroll of the recyclerview. Then in the transition listener i lock the scroll while the card is sliding and unlock it when its finished. It worked pretty well. I can update my answer with code if youd like to see.

Comment: Yes, I would like to check your code, maybe my implementation is not the right way to go to handle the motion between the list and the motionLayout